# angular pattern directive does not work as expected

Tags: angular

I try to implement angular pattern directive for the following input

```
<input style="width: 100%;" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="datepicker" 
       type="text" 
       (focus)="focusFunction()" 
       placeholder="Date de construction" 
       title="Date de construction" 
       pattern="[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}" 
       formControlName="dateConstruction">
```

But I can encode 3 digits for example 456. The system does not complain

Comment: so what you are saying is that when you enter just `456` in the form field then there is no error?

Comment: I am so sorry yes indeed it points an error, I misunderstanded the goal of the directive. What I want is prevent from entering other texte than the pattern

Comment: something like https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/inputmask, then?

Answer (score 0):

The first point is `pattern` is not an Angular directive. It's rather a standard HTML attribute for the tag `input`. It does not forbid you from entering any value you like.

Secondly, you need to implement a real Angular directive which intercepts `keydown` event of the `input` element and passes it or prevent depending on the condition provided in the pattern.

Comment: that is not true, it really is a directive: https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator

Comment: Kind of... The selector is not `[pattern]` but `[pattern][formControlName]` (or other combinations). So, without `formControlName` it would act as a simple attribute.  Any way, I didn't know about such directive. Thanks!

Comment: yea, it wouldn't work without either template form control or reactive form control as it is adding the validator to the form control instance. It cannot do anything without the instance.